# How is line spacing measured in OOXML?

Tags: openxml

I'm trying to translate some formatting specifications from a `.docx` template to LaTeX,
and am trying to get it exact for the academic challenge.

Consider the following Office Open XML snippet:

```
            <w:pPr>
                    <w:widowControl/>
                    <w:spacing w:line="312" w:lineRule="auto"/>
                    <w:jc w:val="both"/>
            </w:pPr>
            <w:rPr>
                    <w:rFonts w:eastAsia="Times New Roman"/>
                    <w:sz w:val="20"/>
            </w:rPr>
```

The line spacing is specified as 312 dxa (or 15.6 [big] points), and the font size is 20 half-points (or 10 [big] points). LibreOffice writer interprets the spacing as `130% proportional`.

What does 312dxa correspond to? Is it the distance from baseline to baseline? How does LibreOffice figure 130%?

15.6 is 130% of 12, which is 1.2 times 10. (For single spacing (in LaTeX) a good rule of thumb is to set `\baselineskip` to 1.2 times the font size). That's my guess.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

According to section 17.3.1.33 of ISO-IEC-29500-1, the semantics of the `after` attribute is modified by the `spacingRule` attribute:

- When `spacingRule` has either of the values `exactly` or `atLeast`, then it expresses a distance between lines as a signed Twips (twentieth of a postscript point) measure.
- When `spacingRule` has the value `auto`, then it expresses a distance in units of 240ths of a line.

In the OP's example, the latter applies, and the space between lines is 312/240=130%.

The OP's original hunch about how line spacing is measured is a good one: the 240 fraction for the `auto` option is probably based on a default case where the baselines of two lines of 10pt type are separated by 1.2 times the the font size, i.e., 240 Twips. In the default case `auto` and `exactly`/`atLeast` have the same behavior for a given value of `after`.

But if the titular question is taken literally, it is not the right question to be asked: the ISO standard specifies exactly the syntax of a OOXML (WML) document. It specifies the semantics of the document in a good amount of detail, but there is an eventual level of granularity beyond which the standard cannot give answers, because they are design decisions that are instead reflected in the vendor-specific implementation.